# How can I detect a long press then activate an animation?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

How can I detect a long press on a touch screen then activate an animation? And when the finger is released, play another animation smoothly? Let's take for example the main character in Crossy Road: when the user presses down, the chicken "squats" and when the user releases their finger, the chicken jumps. Same concept. C#.

Comment: You save the time when the screen is first touched, reset when it's released and each frame when the screen is *still touched* you check how long has it been since the saved time.

Comment: You can view [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html) documentary it should help you with many functions of touch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Input functions to detect these actions.
Following code shows how you can achieve it and I have commented the events when they are true.

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
    {
        //Touch Begin - True when the finger touches the screen
        //Play animation for chicken squat
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButton (0))
    {
        //Touch Continued - True when the finger is still touching the screen
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0))
    {
        //Touch End - True when the finger is lifted from the screen
        //Play animation for chicken jump
    }
}
```

Note: You need to handle a situation where the user touches the menu buttons . Which should not be considered for playing the animation. So for that you need to check your mouse position, whether it is inside a particular area and then only consider the touch for animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can Detect a long press by simply using Touch.deltaTime.

Unity Document Reference : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaTime.html

```
    Touch touch = Input.touches;
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        Touch t = touch[i];
        if (t.deltaTime > 0.2f) // if long touch 
        {
            // do stuff. 

            // If you want to detect long press on an object, do the following.
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(t.position);

            if (Physics.Raycast(pos, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit))
            {
               Debug.Log("Long Pressed on "+hit.transform.name);
            }    

        }
     }
```

Comment: not working,  long press never goes in

Comment: Can you be more specific, what use case it fails for, what your set up is etc

Comment: in  android phone, touch.deltime is always somethong like 0.02-0.03 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an integer value to use as counter, meaning how long the user has kept his finger on the screen to track a long press:

`int timer = 0;`

Then, you're going to detect just an event - the mouse pressed event - and increment the timer at your will:

```
void Update() 
{
    // Increment the timer
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0))
    {
        timer += 1;
        // Additional code for chicken squat
    }
    else if (timer > 0)
    {
        timer = 0;
        // Additional code for chicken jump
    }
}
```

The lower the variables to check for, the more performant your code will be.